# if condition in bash script not working

Tags: bash

For example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
DIR=`dirname $0 `
Save_DIR="Save"
cd $DIR 

if  [ -d $Save_DIR ];then
     rm  $Save_DIR/*
else
     mkdir  $Save_DIR
fi

 for  i  in  $(ls)
 do
     if  [  $i==$Save_DIR ]
     then
         echo "is same "
     fi
 done
```

I think right result  is  a line 'is same', but  we I run it

```
is same 
is same 
is same 
is same 
is same 
is same 
is same 
is same 
is same 
is same
```

It seem the code `if` do nothing, why?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

This necessarily is doing the test `[ -n $i==$Save_DIR ]`, testing if the string is non-empty, because you have not provided any spaces around `=`.

you need to do:

```
[ "$i" = "$Save_DIR" ]
```

`==` is bash-ism, but `[` is not so you should use `=` instead, but would work if you are using `bash`. Quote variables while using `[` to prevent word splitting and filename expansion.

Also don't parse `ls`, you can easily use shell globbing here like:

```
for i in *
```

To match only directories:

```
for i in */
```

Comment: And add a test after changing dir ```cd $DIR ||  exit 1```